# lmplementing both react-native-maps and react-native-google-places-autocomplete

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, google-places-autocomplete

I've been looking online a tutorial that uses both

```
react-native-maps
react-native-google-places-autocomplete
```

but without any luck. Can anyone suggest a project / tutorial that I can study and learn from?